# A problem on topology on $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

$A$ be the closure in $\mathcal{C} [0,1]$ of the set $B$ where $B = \{f \in \mathcal{C}^1 [0,1] \mid \mid f(x) \mid \leq 1 \text{ and } \mid f'(x) \mid \leq 1 \text{ for all } x \in [0,1] \}$, then $B$ is

(Multiple correct)

a) closed

b) compact

c) connected

d) dense

My approach: It is obvious that is closed because we our considering the closure. For compactness I thought of applying Ascoli theorem but I don't know how to show bounded and equicontinious. Also I don't know how to show connected and dense

Comment: You can apply the Ascoli Arzela theorem. Boundedness is given for free in the description of $ B $. Can you use the mean-value theorem to prove equicontinuity?

Comment: Connected follows from the fact that $B$ is path connected (simply via $tf+(1-t)g$) and so $B$ is connected. And the closure of connected subset is connected. Dense is trivial: a closed subset is dense if and only if it is whole space.

Comment: Is the question about $A$ or $B?$

Answer (score 0):

Since the derivatives are uniformly bounded, for any $f \in B$ we have
$$|f(x)-f(y)| \le \max_{z\in [0,1]}\{f'(z)\}|x-y| \le |x-y|, \quad \forall x,y \in [0,1].$$ 
by the mean-value theorem, so $B$ is equicontinuous. This together with uniform boundedness of $B$ means Arzela Asocoli gives us the result.

See @freakish's comments for the others.